# Converting string to INT returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, string, int

i know that there is alot of similar topics posted about similiar problems but none helped me in my case.
I am creating an Insert form for table called product. I am passing data with POST method.
This is the part that is giving me troubles. Since with POST you pass string values, I need to convert the id_category to INT because the type is set to INT in the database. The problem is that when i convert the string value to INT the value that is returned is 0.

```
<form method="POST" action="insert_product.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Kategorija:</td>
<td><select name="category" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">Odaberi kategoriju</option>

<?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<option value='{".$row['id_category']."}'>".$row['category_name']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['id_category']."</option>";
        }
    }
```

This is the part of the code that accepts the data and assigns it to varibles.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $category=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['category'];
 $categoryINT=intval($category);
 $manufacturer=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['manufacturer']);
 $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
 $power=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['power']);
 $catalogue_number=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['catalogue_number']);
 $price=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['price']);
 $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['description']);
 $post_image=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_tmp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

The table is on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/d067ZpS8

Comment: And the value of this string that's being converted to an integer 0 is?

Comment: $row['id_category'] that is INT in the database and those are numbers from 1 to 50 but passing the with post they are converted to string and thats why i need to convert them back to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your select boxes values come like this:

```
"{2}"
```

remove the `{` and `}` in the line starting like this

```
echo "<option value='{".$row['id_category']."}'>
```

so its more like

```
echo "<option value='".$row['id_category']."'>
```

that should work